# Finding a symbol in my own process

Tags: c, linux, dynamic-library

Here's the setup:

1. There's an application `A` that loads `liba.so` (linked at compile time)
2. `liba.so` exports a symbol `expA`
3. I don't control either `A` or `liba.so`
4. Application A can load a library I specify, `libmine.so`, into the same process via `dlopen` (think plugin architecture)
5. I need to use `expA` from `libmine.so` but don't know how to find it without explicitly linking against `liba.so`, which is what I've been doing so far. I assume this won't work in the real world since that symbol is not guaranteed to be at the same address as the one in my local copy of `liba.so` (or is it?). `libmine.so` will be closed-source and can't be recompiled with `A`.

I've never done anything like this, so am a bit unclear on the details of library loading. For example, if I try to `dlopen("liba.so")` from within `libmine.so`, will I get a handle to the already loaded library or a new copy?

In terms of how `libmine.so` is loaded, all I know is that it will be loaded with `RTLD_LAZY` (and nothing else).

Any help and pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the `liba.so` library is `dlopen`ed using `RTLD_GLOBAL`, then you can use `dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "expA")` to find the symbol without needing to reopen the library.

If the `liba.so` library is `dlopen`ed using `RTLD_LOCAL` then you will need to obtain a handle to the library using `dlopen` again within your own `libmine.so`. Note the following:

> If the same library is loaded again with dlopen(), the same file handle is returned. The dl library maintains reference counts for library handles, so a dynamic library is not deallocated until dlclose() has been called on it as many times as dlopen() has succeeded on it. The _init() routine, if present, is only called once. But a subsequent call with RTLD_NOW may force symbol resolution for a library earlier loaded with RTLD_LAZY.

i.e. it's the same copy of the library.

the mechanism is (pseudo), assuming expA is a function: `int expA(int value)`:

```
int (*fpointer)(int) = NULL;

void *handle = dlopen("liba.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);
if (handle != NULL) {
    void *symbol = dlsym(handle, "expA");
    if (symbol != NULL) {
        fpointer = (int (*)(int ))symbol;
    }
}
```

That's pseudo code, with little to no error handling.

Comment: Right. Thanks for that. The thing is, `liba.so` is linked at compile-time (`LD_FLAGS = -la`), so I'm not entirely sure what that ends up looking like at runtime (which is my main confusion, tbh). Will `dlopen` still give me a handle to the existing library even though it was never explicitly `dlopen`ed from `A` (but rather from the linker)?

Comment: I've never had issues using `dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, symbol)` against symbols that are exposed by libraries that are linked as `.so` at compile time at run-time; i.e. you should be just able to `dlsym` without needing to re-do a `dlopen`

Comment: Got it. I've just never dealt with dynamic libraries at this level and am still piecing together the puzzle. Thanks for your time :)